# janrain engage popup to modal window

Tags: janrain

janrain engage facebook login opens in popup window, how to make it open in same window as modal window. Please help me in this. my code is like this,

```
                    janrain.settings.buttonBorderRadius = '2';
                    janrain.settings.buttonBackgroundStyle = 'gray';
                    janrain.settings.language = 'en';
                    janrain.settings.linkClass = 'janrainEngage';
```

I tried adding this, `janrain.settings.flags='stay_in_window';` but it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Include this javascript setting on the page:

```
janrain.settings.popup = false;
```

More info here: http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/widgets/social-sign-in-widget/social-sign-in-widget-api/settings/